# Remove border for Portlet component- Sencha GXT in java

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to remove borders of the portlet as well as the panel.

Below is my code snippet,

```
public class TestViewImpl extends ViewImpl implements TestViewPresenter.MyView{

    private PortalLayoutContainer portal;   

    @Inject
    public TestViewImpl (){
          portal = new PortalLayoutContainer(1);

          vp = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

          portal.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("white");
          portal.setColumnWidth(0, 1);      
          portal.setBorders(false);

          ContentPanel portlet = new Portlet(); 
          portlet.getHeader().setVisible(false);
          portlet.setBorders(false);
          portlet.setBodyBorder(false);
          portlet.add(vp);
          portlet.setResize(true);
          portlet.setBodyStyle("backgroundColor:white;");   
          portal.add(portlet, 0);
```

But somehow the border is always visible.How do I remove the border ? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version is your gxt?

Comment: sencha gxt 3.0.1 @the.wizard

Comment: I tried your code, and inspect the result with developer tools (F12). The border was a background image, which is if we remove it, the whole container will be mess up. What you're trying to achieve? Perhaps I could help you with some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code I can get the borders to disappear (with small alterations to container instantiation). Where are those containers coming from? Are you using UI Binder, if so could you post that code as well.

The blue section that is left is the background from the header. (Hide header hides the text)

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: portal = new PortalLayoutContainer(1);
portal.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("white");
portal.setColumnWidth(0, 1);         
portal.setBorders(false); --> this is what I do with the portallayoutcontainer nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...Where do you create the PortalLayoutContainer?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code in my original post.I dont want  to see any outline for that particular content panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to remove the outline border (which is a background image actually), you can try something like this:

```
Element e = portlet.getElement().getFirstChildElement();
e.getStyle().setBorderWidth(0, Unit.PX);
```

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image: result of remove to border]

It's not going to be easy, but this is the only way (from what I know and tried already), you going to need developer tools on browser (i.e. firebug) to do inspection, and predict what element to get and what attribute to remove. The code I provide above are just example how we can remove the top outline border, and for the rest you can tried it by yourself. Goodluck :-)